# href attribute returns "javascript:void(0)" when parameterized for a function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrape a list of URLs off a website (with requests, beautiful soup, etc.) and access individual URLs to get more information via another function. It works when I am only getting the URLs but if I pass the URLs into a function their values become "javascript:void(0)".

```
url = "https://www.website.com" + content.find('a')['href']
print(url)
# this works fine
```

---

```
def getMore(link){
  response = requests.get(link)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
  ...
  return stuff
}
url = "https://www.website.com" + content.find('a')['href']
more = getMore(url)
# this returns "...pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: javascript:void(0)"
```

I'm not sure what's the issue here because I did this before with other sites.

EDIT: Clarification

Comment: You are expecting to receive a full, valid URL as the value of the `href` attribute. But on reality it can any kind of relative URL, just a fragment, JavaScript code or even total nonsense. You have to handle all these cases.

Comment: I did, and the same issue persists, say if I add "https://www.website.com" in front of it, the result will be "https://www.website.comjavascript:void(0)". I'm sorry for not clarifying that in the question.

Comment: Is `website.comjavascript:void(0)` a valid URL?

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue, all of the URLs are valid URLs except for the first one which caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the first item of the array happened to be void which is why the requests could not process it. I ignored the first item and everything is working now.